# Dart/Flutter super(key:key) example

Tags: flutter, dart

Take this code for a constructor for a stateful widget:

```
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);
```

Is this the same as writing the following:

```
MyHomePage(Key key, String title) {
     super(key);
     this.title = title;
}
```

Furthermore, I understand that the first ':' starts the initializer list, or the functions that must be called before the constructor at hand -- in this case, "MyHomePage".

Is there any situation where there are other functions there other than - or in addition to - super?

Comment: you can check out the [official docs](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#initializer-list) to see what can be done with an initializer list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the first question:

No, it wouldn't work because the super class was already constructed, and you'll get this error: `The expression doesn't evaluate to a function, so it can't be invoked`

For the second question:

Beside initializing fields and calling the constructor of the super class, assertions are also used in the initializer list during development (see when it works [here](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#assert)), for example:

```
import 'dart:math';

class Point {
  final num x;
  final num y;
  final num distanceFromOrigin;

  Point(x, y)
      : assert(x < y),
        x = x,
        y = y,
        distanceFromOrigin = sqrt(x * x + y * y);
}

main() {
  var p = new Point(2, 3);
  print(p.distanceFromOrigin);
}
```

Reference: 
[Language Tour - Initializer List](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#initializer-list)